# merging branch to master as copy to subdirectory

Tags: git, merge, directory

I've got a repo with configuration information in it. It's managed in branches with a one-to-one mapping of branches to environments. Every branch contains a file foo.txt at its root. The branches are named A, B, C and so on.

I've decided that having branches for config environments is a pain and would rather just have directories instead. What I would like to do is take the contents of the branches, and have them exist in master under directories. So instead of branches A, B, and C, I'd have directories A, B and C, each containing their foo.txt.

The fly in the ointment is that I'd like to preserve history.

I tried going into branch A, branching off its first commit into A-moved, and having an alternate history on the moved branch history appear. e.g.

```
git co [sha of first commit on A]
git co -b A-moved
mkdir A
git mv foo.txt A
git commit -m "moved for A"
git cherry-pick A ^A-moved ^master
```

I then tried, back on master, making a directory called A, and creating a foo.txt in that which contained the same content as the first commit on branch A. Then I tried cherry-picking from the A-moved branch, but pretty much made a mess of conflicts.

```
git co master
mkdir A
cd A
echo "blah blah" >foo.txt
git commit -am "first entry in A dir"
git cherry-pick A-moved ^A ^master
** KABOOM O' CONFLICTS **
```

I must be going about this all wrong and would love some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Had a friend answer this on twitter. The answer is of course using git filter-branch to rewrite the history of the branches in question. First make a snippet of shell to do the directory creating and moving:

```
  $ cat >~/move-foo.sh
  if [ -f foo.txt ]; then mkdir $1; git mv foo.txt $1; fi
  (Ctrl-D)
```

Then run the filter branch:

```
  git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sh ~/move-foo.sh A' -f A
```

Branch A's history will then look like it was on subdirectory A all along, at which point you can just merge it into master and you're done. Yay!

Comment: With `filter-branch` you rewrite the history and thus introduce new commits (ids). Is this what you want or do you want a new commit on top that consolidates the branches?

Comment: René, I'm OK with creating new commits based off the old ones on the branches. This solution works well enough for me.